# Python: How to get the value in a dictionary by key, if the dictionary key is a class object?

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, graph, python-class

Beginner here, and I was wondering if this is possible, or if this is even the right way to approach the problem.

**The overall idea is to have a graph of different nodes, where each node could be (as in the following case) a Person or maybe a location, or something else.**

**I thought the best way to represent the graph nodes and relations would be to have a dictionary of sets, where the dictionary keys are nodes, and it's values represent the directional arcs (key1 -> key1value1, key1 -> key1value2).**

So I have a simple class called Person:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.name, ) == (other.name, )

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name,))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

I then have a dictionary, in which both the key and the values are class objects:

```
classdict = {}
classdict[Person("James")] = {Person("Maria")}
classdict[Person("James")].add(Person("Bonita"))
```

Okay, so far so good. When I do a `print(classdict)`, the response is:

```
{James: {Maria, Bonita}}
```

And a quick type check reveals that they're all class objects:

```
for k, v in classdict.items():
    print(type(k))
    print(type(list(v)[0]))
    print(type(list(v)[1]))
```

prints:

```
<class '__main__.Person'>
<class '__main__.Person'>
<class '__main__.Person'>
```

But now, I am confused as to how do I work with this?
For example, I would want to access the dictionary values by key where the name attribute is `James`. How would I do that? Silly me, I tried `print(classdict["James"])` which obviously did not work, and throws me a `KeyError`.

Comment: To access the dictionary values where the name is James you will have to search for the hashed object Person("James"), so print(classdict[Person("James")]) will give you the values {Bonita, Maria}

Comment: @bp7070 Okay, that was embarrassingly simple thing that I overlooked. And yes, it works! Thank you!

Comment: I do not test but I think if you define `__has__` as: `return hash(self.name)` then the `classdict["James"]` will work.